# Why does Timeout.timeout(sec) not work with activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, timeout

I have the following code running to catch any SQL statements that might get hung.  While trying to test this, I wrote a horibly optimized sql statement that takes over a minute to run.  I put a 20 second timeout wrapper around an activerecord execute sql statement, but it doesn't seem to interrupt the sql call for taking to long.  This is running against Oracle databases.

```
  start_time = Time.now
  Timeout.timeout(20) do #20 timeout for long running sql
    @connection.connection.execute(sql_string)
  end
  total_sql_time = Time.now - start_time
  puts "Sql statement took #{total_sql_time} seconds
```

output

```
  Sql statement took 64 seconds
```

Comment: This is not the case with postgresql. Doing this `Timeout.timeout(2) {  Product.connection.execute('select pg_sleep(10) ') }` will invoke exception.

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar Mine invokes the exception HOWEVER it will still wait to get the response before the exception is thrown

Comment: The best place to ask this question would be the mailing list for the oracle-enhanced_adapter. Back when I was using Oracle it answered all kinds of questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

(Just a guess…)

Ruby's `Timeout.timeout()` is probably operating in much the same way as the [equivalent function in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), which is to say that it counts time executed within Ruby, and stops counting when you're waiting for database queries to run, waiting to finish reading or writing files, waiting to for a network request to complete, etc. — i.e. waiting for anything IO-related.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I don't have much experience with Rails backed by Oracle, but there's the timeout option in the database config file.

```
# config/database.yml
production:
  ...
  timeout: 20000
```

It's in milliseconds.

If I can assume you are in the development environment, you might want to explicitly set your `explain` timeout and review the console log:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds 20
```

Comment: Do you have a link where I can read into timeout a little more?  Everything I read is on connection timeout not running sql timeout

Answer (score 1):

Remember that ActiveRecord is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), which is to say it's a layer of abstraction that sits on top of your database.

This is important in the context of what happens when `Timeout.timeout` executes. Database adapters are responsible for taking a command in ruby and converting them into commands that are executed in your database, an entirely different process.

When a timeout happens, the call to `@connection.connection.execute`, as a ruby command, is interrupted in the adapter but not the sql code itself as you've noted.

You should be able to make use of the optional Exception Class parameter `klass` in `Timeout.timeout` to specify a signal/command to send to your database in order to cancel the query itself. However this would depend on your database adapter. [Here's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html) the `kill query` command I would try to execute if I were using mysql.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't seem the ruby command is interrupted in the adapter, because even though I hit the timeout the program waits until it gets a response from the query.

Comment: see updated question... this will more clearly state what I mean by it won't kill the thread

Comment: I guess Oracle adapter is somehow causes Global Interpreter Lock is not being released - that is the only thing which can break Timeout.timeout, because the intepreter (or the VM) does not get back the control until the SQL data is arrived.

Could you try out this stuff with JRuby and Oracle JDBC driver?

Comment: @GaborGarami I actually am using JRuby with the Oracle JDBC driver (OJDBC6.jar) Here are the records from my Gemfile. 
gem 'activerecord', '4.0.4'
gem 'ActiveRecord-JDBC', '0.5'
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', '1.3.6'